# What is that ? Resource.Id.fragmentContainer does not contain definition for fragmentContainer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

(Main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity class

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ActionBarTabsExample
{
    [Activity (Label = "ActionBar Tabs Example", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {   
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        //enable navigation mode to support tab layout
            this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        //adding audio tab
        AddTab ("Audio", Resource.Drawable.Icon,  new AudioFragment());

        //adding video tab 
            AddTab ("Video", Resource.Drawable.Icon,  new VideoFragment());
        }

        /*
         * This method is used to create and add dynamic tab view
         * @Param,
         *  tabText: title to be displayed in tab
         *  iconResourceId: image/resource id
         *  fragment: fragment reference
         * 
        */
        void AddTab (string tabText, int iconResourceId, Fragment fragment)
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();            
            tab.SetText (tabText);
            tab.SetIcon (iconResourceId);

            // must set event handler for replacing tabs tab
            tab.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e) {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
            };

            this.ActionBar.AddTab (tab);
        }      

    }
}
```

`e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);`

App don't see any fragmentContainer tag. How to solve it? I dev on VS 2015(android xamarin).

> Resource.Id.fragmentContainer does not contain definition for fragmentContainer.

Comment: You called addtab before oncreate maybe

Comment: Nothing. It still show my button up

Comment: Xamarin has a lot of issues with resources. Do a clean/rebuild first, that sometimes helps.

Comment: Is that a build error or runtime error ? i.e, Resource.Designer.cs don't have fragmentContainer or does that throw a null Exception in runtime ?

Comment: I did it as you said but Nothing

Comment: @Sreerai It don't look up fragmentContainer of id of framelayout

Comment: Building resutls:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'fragmentContainer' visual studio 2015\Projects\...\MainActivity.cs 20 Active